# Render Multiple View/Controller Pairs

Tags: javascript, list, view, controller, ember.js

I am currently rendering a list of views:

```
  <ul>
    {{#each newsItem in controller}}
      {{view App.NewsItemView contentBinding="newsItem" class="news-item" }}
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
```

But I would like to inject a NewsItemController into each view.

I've tried using `render`, but this only seems to support a single view, giving the exception:

> Uncaught Error:  Handlebars error: Could not find property 'control'
>   on object .

I've found a brief mention of using `control` instead, but this no longer seems to be included.

**So how can I render multiple versions of the same view, injecting a separate controller into each one?**

Answer (score 1):

`{{render}}` should be fixed in current master (if you build it from Github).  You should be able to use it multiple times if you pass a model:

```
<ul>
 {{#each controller}}
   {{render "newsItem" this}}
 {{/each}}
</ul>
```

`{{control}}` is still there but hidden behind a flag (because it's still experimental).  To use it you need to do : `ENV.EXPERIMENTAL_CONTROL_HELPER = true` before including the `ember.js` file.  If you can avoid using it, it would be better.

However I think the simplest approach would be to use `itemController`:

```
<ul>
  {{#each controller itemController="newsItem"}}
    {{view App.NewsItemView class="news-item" }}
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

I think you can combine them to make it simpler (I haven't tried it yet):

```
<ul>
  {{each controller itemController="newsItem" itemViewClass="App.NewsItemView"}}
</ul>
```