# Multiple Instances of the Same Controller Simultaneously in Ember

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, controller, ember.js

Just been watching the Ember Peepcode video. One thing it has hammered home to me is that Controllers are singletons, so a single instance of each Controller is created at runtime and the controller's data property is swapped in/out as needed.

But what happens when you need multiple versions of the same controller on screen and active at the same time. What happens if I have multiple `example.handlebars` templates, each of which needs to be backed by its own version of `ExampleController` on screen simultaneously?

**How does Ember handle this situation?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several ways to handle that (mentioned in my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15702960/1765925)).

Method 1:

`{{render}}` with a model (needs latest Ember.js build):

```
{{render "example" example1}}
{{render "example" example2}}
```

Method 2:

#### Update July 7 2014: `{{control}}`  has been removed from Ember >= 1.0.

`{{control}}` (it is still buggy so avoid if you can)

```
{{control "example"}}
```

But first you need to enable the flag: `ENV.EXPERIMENTAL_CONTROL_HELPER = true` before loading ember.js file.

There's also a bug which you'll need to fix by doing:

```
App.register('controller:example', App.ExampleController, {singleton: false }
```

Method 3:

Using `{{each}}` with `itemController`.

```
{{#each controller itemController="example"}}
  {{view "example"}}
{{/each}}
```

Each of these will create a new separate instance every time.

Comment: But what happens when I have to access one of those controllers.How do I do that? For example if I have to set some value to the controller from the route I may have to use controllerFor approach but it works for singleton controller only.

Comment: You can bind a value on that controller to a singleton controller.  By updating the singleton, the property on that controller will sync.

Comment: But in that case when that singleton controller changes the value all my controllers will receive the update. And all will respond but I need only one specific. And also, this approach works when my changes ripple from the controller to the singleton controller but not the other way round.

Comment: An example of such a case in a jsbin would be helpful.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/igozob/9/edit
In this example single click is  handled internally but the double click has to communicate with router of singleton controller thus not getting updated

Comment: Seems strange that you would want to handle that in the route.  You can handle the click in the controller: http://jsbin.com/EqigeDa/1/edit . However if for some reason not obvious in this example you need the route to handle the event, you can do this: http://jsbin.com/EqigeDa/2/edit

Answer (score 0):

What I've found is that if you override the init method of the controller and set content to a fresh object (or whatever you're using), you can have multiple independent instances.

```
App.MyMultipleController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    content: {},

    init: function(){
        this.set('content', {});
        return this._super.call(this, arguments);
    }
});
```

Here's a JSFiddle. It's using `ObjectProxy`, for my own purposes, but you could use `ObjectController` if you wanted: http://jsfiddle.net/jgillick/D83d8/